# Having trouble returning 404 responses with asyncio/aiohttp

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

```
import time
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def is_name_available(s, name):
    async with s.get("https://twitter.com/%s" % name) as res:
        if res.raise_for_status == 404:
            print('%s is available!' % name)
            return name

async def check_all_names(names):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(raise_for_status=True) as s:
        tasks = []
        for name in names:
            task = asyncio.create_task(is_name_available(s, name))
            tasks.append(task)
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

def main():    
    with open('names.txt') as in_file, open('available.txt', 'w') as out_file:        
        names = [name.strip() for name in in_file]
        start_time = time.time()
        results = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(check_all_names(names))
        results = [i for i in results if i]
        out_file.write('\n'.join(results))
        print(f'[ <? ] Checked {len(names)} words in {round(time.time()-start_time, 2)} second(s)')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to go about returning only 404'd links in is_name_available with this asyncio/aiohttp structure I'm using from another project of mine. I'm a beginner in python and any help is appreciated.

Comment: On top of the excellent answer you got, you can use `asyncio.run(check_all_names(names))` without getting the event loop explicitly

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
        if res.raise_for_status == 404:
```

`raise_for_status` is a *method*, so you're supposed to call it, not compare it to a number (which will always return false). And in your case, you don't want to call `raise_for_status` in the first place because you don't want to raise an exception when encountering 404, but detect it. To detect 404, you can simply write:

```
        if res.status == 404:
```

Also note that you don't want to specify `raise_for_status=True` because it will raise an exception for 404 before the `if` gets a chance to run.